# Dynamically generated TextBox and Input Bindings : Where to put the Commands

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, command

I'm generating a List of TextBoxes within an ItemsControl like so :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentCandidate.Properties}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel>
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
      <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
          <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{?}" CommandParameter={?} Key="PgUp" />
            <KeyBinding Command="{?}" CommandParameter={?} Key="Enter" />
          </TextBox.InputBindings>
     </TextBox>
       </Border>
     </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Within the input-Bindings I want to access a Command that's available at ViewModel-Level, at the same level as the ItemsSource, that is. In Order to access it from within the ItemTemplate, I used the following workaround up to now :

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCurrentCandidate"
               Tag="{Binding Path=CurrentCandidate}"
               Visibility="Hidden"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbReset"
               Tag="{Binding Path=ResetInputCommand}"
               Visibility="Hidden"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbValidate"
               Tag="{Binding Path=ValidateCommand}"
               Visibility="Hidden"></TextBlock>
```

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ElementName=tbReset, Path=Tag}"
   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tbCurrentCandidate, Path=Tag}"
   Key="PgUp" />
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ElementName=tbValidate, Path=Tag}"
   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tbCurrentCandidate, Path=Tag}"
   Key="Enter" />
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

This is a HTML-Hidden-Field-like workaround to access the properties that are not available where I need them, but I suppose there must be a better way than that...

Anyone who can help me out : feel hugged for making that piece of misery a bit less miserable ;-)

Comment: Did you try using something like `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=Name}`? Replace ItemsControl by the parent control type that has a DataContext containing the desired commands.

Comment: Yeah, that's one thing I found working : {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path =DataContext.ResetInputCommand}. It's not really beautiful, but it works

Comment: Since there's no other response yet : you could post this as one, so i can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=Name}
```

Replace `ItemsControl` by the parent control type that has a `DataContext` containing the desired commands.

Answer (score 0):

Why not in your base view model class have a parent property which would be a view model base. Then in your XAML you can simply bind to Parent.TheCommand.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The model's parent item.
    /// </summary>
    protected ViewModelBase _parent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">Optional Parameter, The model's parent model. </param>
    public ViewModelBase(ViewModelBase parent = null)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The model's parent model.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelBase Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
    }

    //All other common properties and methods.
 }
```

because the binding in XAML is dynamic it doesn't need to be the concrete type of the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I don't intend to bloat my ViewModels any further by creating navigation properties.